# TreeView using HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I've been wrapping myself around the axle for days now.

What I'm trying to do is create a `UserControl` that has a `TreeView` in it. The `TreeView` is supposed to display information about a `Show`, and a `Show` has a list of `Instructions` in it, and so on and so forth...

I've tried to do this in various ways, but I can't get the data to show up. Here's some of my code snippets that I've tried:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Show}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Instructions}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ShowName}"/>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sounds}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

And I've also tried...

```
<DockPanel>
        <DockPanel.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type show:Show}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Instructions}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ShowName}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type show:Instruction}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Sounds}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type show:SoundInstruction}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type show:NodeInstruction}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DockPanel.Resources>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Show}">
        </TreeView>
    </DockPanel>
```

But nothing seems to work. In my `MainWindow`, I have this code which initializes the data context:

```
            Show s = new Show("Hamlet");
            s.AddInstruction(new Instruction("Inst1"));
            s.AddInstruction(new Instruction("Inst2"));
            ShowViewModel vm = new ShowViewModel(s);
            DataContext = vm;
```

Any help in the matter will be greatly appreciated.

Jake

Comment: Do you get any binding errors in output window?

Comment: From `System.Data`? Like not being able to find the property Show in the DataContext? No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ItemsSource has to bind to something that is `IEnumerable`. From your code, it looks like your `ShowViewModel.Show` is a property that is of type `Show`, a single object. That will not work, you have to turn it into a collection (`ObservableCollection`, preferably).

The second way you used to define templates (side-by-side, not nested), is definitely nicer.

Also, assuming you don't set `DataContext` to anything else between your `Window` and `DockPanel`, you can change this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Show}">
```

to this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Show}">
```

Your data context is automatically inherited down the visual tree.

Comment: Ok that made much more sense. So in order for the template to be applied, the item in question has to be a collection, it can't just be an object... That makes much more sense. The `Show` already had an `ObservableCollection` of Instructions, so I can use that. Thanks a lot.